# Different view for mobile applications using play framework

Tags: java, mobile, playframework

Is it possible to have different views (html / css) for mobile devices based on the user-agent header in the play framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course this is possible. You can get the HTTP-Header and detect if it was a mobile device. Then you can deliver different templates or set variables which was interpreted at your template. See for example this [Thread](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/e686e8fdff545a4c/b6545d6b355271b0?lnk=gst&q=mobile#b6545d6b355271b0) at the google-group. 
I hope this shows you the right direction. Don't have the time to write a whole solution.

Comment: Perfect. Just wanted to know that it's possible.